# How can I check using an if condition whether the end of string has reached in Java

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I need a program that replaces a word in a string. Its working fine except for the part that I can't reach the end of string. 
My code

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter string");
original = keyboard.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter word");
word = keyboard.next();
System.out.println("Enter new word");
omit = keyboard.next();
length = original.length();
for (i= 0; i< length; i++) {
    c = original.charAt(i);
    if (c != ' ') {
       nword = nword + c;
    }
    else {
       if (nword.equals(word)) {
           nword = omit;
       }
       nword = nword + " ";
       duplicate = duplicate + nword;
       nword = "";
    }           
}
System.out.print(duplicate);
keyboard.close();
```

Here, the last word in the string will not be added to `nword` unless there is a space in the end of string. How can I check for the end of string `original`

Comment: Why not use `String.replace()`? Is this homework?

Comment: `System.out.print(original.replace(word, omit));`

Comment: For this kind of question, you probably should remove the Scanners and use static String. This would be easier to read. You should explain what you mean by _end of string original_

Answer (score 0):

I think that after the `for` loop you need a variant of the code in your else part to get the last word appended to `duplicate`. Something like:

```
   if (nword.equals(word)) {
       nword = omit;
   }
   // don’t append a space this time
   duplicate = duplicate + nword;
```

Not tested.